# Operator in Java like // in python?

Tags: java, python, operators

Is there a form of the // operator that is used in python that I can use in java, or some sort of workaround?
    10 // 3 = 3

Comment: 10 / 3 will have the same behavior. Java performs integer division if both operand are int (or long)

Answer (score 5):

In python 3 `//` act as a floor division by default.

In python 2.2 and later 2.X version we can import it from the `__future__`

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 10/3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10//3
3
```

In Java:
When dividing floating-point variables or values, the fractional part of the answer is represented in the floating-point variable.

```
float f = 10.0f / 6.0f; // result is 1.6666
double d = 10.0 / 9.0; // result is 1.1111
```

But for floor in java:

```
(int)Math.floor(10/3);
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to notice is:

in python 3:

6 // -132 = -1

in java:

6 / -132 = 0

Comment: For interger division in python, we need:       math.trunc(a / float(b))

Comment: Very surprising that very few seem to be aware of this - Python integer division (old or new) was *never* like C/Java integer division, unless there are only non-negative integers in your universe.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int python_like_divisor(int x, int y) {
    final remainder = x % y;
    if(remainder != 0) {
        return (x - remainder) / y;
    }
    return x / y;
}
```

Some basic math knowledge is good ;)

With float-point (float, double etc.) values this method will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-)
java.lang.Math#floorDiv(int, int)

Answer (score -1):

Java's integer division will act in the same way as the // operator in Python. This means that something like this:

```
(int) 9/4 == 2 is True
```

The cast here is even unnecessary because both 9 and 4 are integers. If one was a float or a double this cast would be necessary as java would no longer execute this statement as integer division. To be more explicit you could do this

```
(int)Math.floor(9 / 4);
```

which divides the numbers first and then floors the results to the nearest integer.